# Dynamic Styles from redux store in react native

Tags: css, react-native, redux

I want to use dynamic css style in react native app. Currently I am using css style from a file say Contants.js like this

```
export default {   
Colors: {      
    headerBackColor : '#7d1f7d',
    headerColor: '#EEFF41',           
   }    
}
```

Then I use this in components like this
import Constants from '../../Constants';

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({ 
card: {
     backgroundColor: Constants.Colors.headerBackColor,
      }
});
```

I want to change headerBackColor from redux store. How can I do it???? any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to handle only the theme with redux and store the colors like you was doing.

Reducer

```
let initialState = {theme: 'light'}

export default function themeManager(state = initialState, action){
    let nextState
    switch (action.type){
        case 'SET_THEME':
            if(action.theme)
            nextState = {
                ...state,
                theme: action.theme
            }
            return nextState
    default:
        return state
    }
}
```

Component

```
<Header style={this.props.theme === 'light' ? Constants.Colors.lightHeader : Constants.Colors.darkHeader}>...</Header>
```

Exporting your component

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    theme: state.theme
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(YourComponent)
```